# How to tell if 700mm tires fit 29" rims?

Tags: tire

My MTB has 29" x 2.25" tires on it now.  I'm looking at these 700mm x 35mm tires to replace them.  Will they fit a 29" rim?

Comment: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html  Note that there is no such thing as a 29" rim.

Comment: Aside, 700c is not 700mm, its probably 622mm with a tiny chance of being 630mm.  Wheel/rim/tyre sizing is strange.

Comment: An additional comment, I used to replace my MTB's tires to narrow city tyre. However, this is the stupidest thing I personally think I have ever done. It does not improve speed much but I lose the enjoyment of the MTB riding. There are plenty fast track MTB tires to consider and I would personally recommend thinking and planning in this direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three factors to check:

**Factor 1. Diameter.** If your wheel is a standard 29", then it equals 700c or 622mm. They are different convension name of the same diameter for different types of bicycle markets.

29" = 700c = 622

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/29er_(bicycle)

**Factor 2. Clearance**

Since, 35mm is much narrorer than 2.25" (~57mm), the clearance will not be any problem at all. Your current bicycle frame will have much clearances to install 35mm tyres.

**Factor 3. The specificiation of the wheelset**

The final factor to check is to go through the specification of the wheelset.

The official specification will tell if the tyre width is compatible with the wheel.

For an example: MAVIC Crossmax Pro <-- A MTB XC wheelset

In the specification of it, you will see

#1 The RIM size is **ETRTO size 29": 622x22TSS**

#2 Recommended tyre sizes: **46mm to 64mm (1.8" to 2.5")**

Since 35mm is narrorer than the official recommendation, in the case of MAVIC Crossmax Pro, it will be **not recommended** to install a 700x35C tyre.

PS. Please don't argue the **marketing or not marketing** with me. It is a free world. Anyone can try any **not recommended** combination as his/her free willings but I just can't give the answer of the kind.